# New activity display pushes down the questions list

Tags: feature-request, bug

One thing that has happened to me now a couple of times, is that the same millisecond I am clicking on a link to a question, the "n messages with activity" display at the top of the list pushes down the link I had just clicked, so that what I actually clicked at that time is a link no more.

My suggestion is to reserve that space for the message so that the list wouldn't move.

Comment: This is really a meta.SE issue.